# Angularjs menu alter body top position?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I try to add a dropdown menu item in a fixed div. But when the menu pops out, my body element is set with a negative "top" property.

Here's an exemple on codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLdzQG

When triggered, the body element offset is changed with a "top" property that seems to be based on my ".under" class margin-top property :

```
style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: -87.2031px; overflow: hidden;"
```

Can someone tell me why and how to avoid this ? With Chrome this provide a white box at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **angular material**, wrap screen column layout and assign flex to div as per requirements.

[Angular Material layout doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container)

remove all the css tricks you have done. in CSS just kept background colors and tag questions properly so others can help

```
    <div layout="column" class="md-menu-demo menudemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div  flex class="top">
      <md-menu>
        <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
          <md-icon md-menu-origin="" md-svg-icon="call:phone"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content width="4">
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="ctrl.redial($event)">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="call:dialpad" md-menu-align-target=""></md-icon>
              Redial
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button disabled="disabled" ng-click="ctrl.checkVoicemail()">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="call:voicemail"></md-icon>
              Check voicemail
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="ctrl.toggleNotifications()">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="social:notifications-{{ctrl.notificationsEnabled ? 'off' : 'on'}}"></md-icon>
              {{ctrl.notificationsEnabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable' }} notifications
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
  </div>
  <div flex class="under">

  <div><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p><p>6</p><p>7</p><p>8</p><p>9</p><p>0</p><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p><p>6</p><p>7</p><p>8</p><p>9</p><p>0</p></div>
  </div>
```