# Angular material menu: a view appeared when I click on menu button

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I try to add a material menu component to view. But when I click the menu (to see it's options) it seems that a view is rendered over other components. I don't want this view to be rendered. How can I prevent that?

This is my code:

```
<body id="page-top" class="landing-page" style="background:transparent !important;">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper" style="position:absolute !important; margin:0">
        <md-menu>
            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button">
                Click here to see menu items
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content flex width="4" ng-model="$ctrl.ingredient">
                <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.ingredients">
                    <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.insertIngredient(item.title, $event, field.Name, field.Type)"> <span md-menu-align-target>{{item.title}}</span> </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angular js:

```
this.openMenu = function ($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
            originatorEv = ev;
            $mdOpenMenu(ev);
        };
```

I inspect the page by chrome. It seems that after clicking menu, CSS property "top" is added as style to body tag. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to remove that.

I also see the question: [Angularjs menu alter body top position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978004/angularjs-menu-alter-body-top-position) however it doesn't help me anymore.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to change the "top" position because you want the menu to be lower? OR are you trying to prevent the menu's "open" animation? What is the goal? Not sure i understand ;)

Comment: No I don't want the menu to be lower. I said the problem. When I click the menu button (to see menu items), a view is rendered over the page's components. Actually it covers the components and makes them invisible. @DotBot